# How to stop SimpleAnalytics from counting self views?

Tags: javascript, analytics

I am using [SimpleAnalytics](https://www.simpleanalytics.com/) for my website. But I do not want the views to be recorded when I myself visit the website. Is there any good solution available for this?

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but are you really concerned about your visits throwing off your analytics stats meaningfully? Analytics aren't super useful usually without a somewhat sizeable sample of users.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the founder of Simple Analytics. We have [an extension](https://docs.simpleanalytics.com/extension) that you can use. You could also dynamically load the script when it's not you.